# Ability to add more required reviewers once PR starts?

Tags: azure-devops

We have a common case where we have a PR that has default required reviewers set from branch policies. Once the review starts, the reviewers decide that they would like to add another person that is required, based on their intuition, and not just based on path or file name filters.

This doesn't seem possible as when the user adds a new reviewer, it always seems to go into optional reviewers, and there's no way to "promote" that reviewer to required.

Is this possible and we're missing it, or is it something that would have to be added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The required reviewers can only be set in the branch policy. Reviewers added after the start of pr can only be optional, and the requirements cannot be promoted to required.
So I think it is impossible to directly added required reviewers once pr starts.

One way to deal with your issue is that you can add the required reviewers to a group, and then add the group as a required reviewer in the **Automatically include code reviewers** field of the branch policy. When you want to add more new required reviewers once pr starts,you can add these new reviewers to the group.

In addition, until now, in our official feature suggestion for Azure Devops forum, there has been a such suggestion exist in it: [Allow adding required reviewers per Pull Request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/412370/allow-adding-required-reviewers-per-pull-request.html). You can comment and vote it there. Our PM and Product Group are reviewing these suggestion regularly and considering take it as plan.

Comment: Thanks Hugh. That doesn't cut it here since each pull request is a case by case basis and we can't be adding or removing to users in a group on per-PR basis. I've added my comment and upvoted that thread, thank you.